# Is meat/fish eaten in the Kung Fu Panda universe?

Tags: kung-fu-panda

The [Kung Fu Panda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_Fu_Panda_(franchise)) universe contains both carnivores (tigers, leopards, wolves, crocodiles etc.) and animals commonly eaten, both by those and in Chinese cuisine (pigs, ducks/geese, cattle, sheep etc.). All of these are portrayed as sentient and one would assume that they are thus not part of the diet. I can't recall any reference to them being eaten.

As far as I'm aware we don't see any sentient fish or prawn in the series, although I haven't seen all TV episodes, only a handful as well as all the movies and short film specials. It's possible those might be non-sentient and used as food, similar to how it is in [Redwall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redwall).

The food portrayed in the series doesn't explicitly show meat, but there are things like dumplings (often but not always filled with meat or seafood) and noodle soup (usually served in a broth cooked from animal bones). Still, so far everything seems consistent with everyone being vegan, even the carnivores.

There are a few doubts. Mantis blissfully talks about a future girlfriend biting his head off, referring to real mantises sometimes practicing sexual cannibalism. From Tigress' childhood we know that predators can be feared by others because of their greater power and potential for violence. With *some* parts of real world biology referenced, the fact that many carnivorous animals cannot in fact live on a vegan diet also bears mention again - then again they can cook and eat noodles, so clearly realism isn't much of a factor.

So basically what I'm asking is: while it seems likely that nobody in the Kung Fu Panda universe eats meat, is there in fact an official canon answer to this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found this [source](https://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/kung-fu-panda.htm) that quotes one of the directors of the first film, John Stevenson as saying

> "Everybody is vegetarian, even our predatory characters—otherwise it got too weird," explains Stevenson.

That is the only evidence/canonical answer I can find regarding the dietary habits of characters in the Kung Fu Panda universe.

Answer (score 4):

Nothwithstanding [the quote](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/237052/20774) from the co-director of the first film that "*everyone is vegetarian*", there do seem to be **several instances where we see animals prepared and eaten as food**.

[image]
Grubs and crickets are boiled and served in a stew in [KFP:PoD - *Poison in the Pit of Plum*](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Poison_in_the_Pit_of_Plum)

[image]
King prawns are served 'shell-on' in [KFP:PoD - *A Game of Fists*](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/A_Game_of_Fists)

---

The Dreamworks licenced first-reader book [*Po's Tasty Training*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00134TC4M) shows Po getting ready to eat a range of meat-based foods; lobster, slug, clam, and frog.

[image]

Terrifyingly, the tie-in book *[Kung Fu Panda 2 : Po & Ping's recipe storybook](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21142702-kung-fu-panda-2)* ("*learn how to make some of the Ping family's secret recipes!*") features a wide range of animals *that we know to be intelligent* being eaten including chicken, pork, and beef.

[image]